# Standard Unlit shader doesn't work?

Tags: unity, shaders

I created a project to download and try out free Unity assets. I then transfer the assets I actually want to use to my actual project which uses the LWRP render pipline.

I tried to get some particle system. I copied all settings and then I found that the shader "Standard Unlit" is not working in my project. I tried to use the LWRP shaders but they didn't give me the same results. How to solve this?

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 1):

The LWRP shader in your project uses "Color Mode: Additive" while the standard shader in the LWRP project uses "Color Mode: Multiply". The result is that those areas where a lot of particles with a very low intensity accumulate create a halo in your shader.

Comment: What you see is the best result I can get. I did what you said and the [result](https://i.postimg.cc/7ZY2Qqmh/sv.png) is bad. No matter what I do I can't get close to the one in unity asset. If you have time please try download [Unity Particle Pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/unity-particle-pack-127325) and copy fire particles to your project as I did. Is it a bug ?